# Efficiently returning the next larger value of a non-existing key in scala's sorted collections?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In scala, given a sorted map, tree or list, what is the most efficient way to return the next larger value of a non-existing key? Additionally, is it possible to get an "iterator/cursor" starting at this element?

**Edit:**

I'm happy with any interpretation of "efficiently", e.g. "runtime", "memory usage", "clarity" or "taking the smallest possible amount of programmer time to implement and maintain" (thanks Kevin Wright).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `SortedMap`, then you can call `range` on it. Well, sort of. It is broken up to 2.8.1 if you plan to add and/or remove elements from the map afterwards. It should be ok if you avoid these operations, and it has been fixed for upcoming Scala versions as well.

Comment: `range` or the alternatives `from` and `to` seems to be the best way to do this.

Comment: Doesn't range require elements that are in the collection?

Comment: @JamesMoore No. It will use those elements as boundaries, but it does not require them to be on the collection.

Answer (score 2):

*Defining "efficiently" as "taking the smallest possible amount of programmer time to implement and maintain"...*

For a Sequence:

```
val s = Seq(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41)
val overSixteen = s dropWhile (_ < 16)
```

For a Map:

```
val s = Map(2->"a", 3->"b", 5->"c", 7->"d", 11->"e", 13->"f")
val overSix = s dropWhile (_._1 < 6)
```

If you prefer an Iterator, just call `.iterator` on the resulting collection, or you can use `.view` *before* `dropWhile` if you're especially interested in lazy behaviour.

Comment: you'd want to do `seq dropWhile (_ < y) headOption` in case of there being no such value

Comment: @oxbow_lakes As I read it, the requirement was to return not just just first element above a given value, but the entire following sequence.  If there is no such value then the returned sequence is empty, but you can still map against it or, indeed, call `headOption` if you only truly want that one value.